# Javascript in Wordpress: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-visualization

I am trying to call a function that is a part of an external javascript file. I get the following error in Line 1 of the .js file.

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "

I also get the following error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: drawcolChart is not defined".

drawcolChart is the name of the function that I am calling.

I am calling drawcolChart from another function in the functions.php file of wordpress. The related code is appended below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

drawcolChart('inc_exp_chart');

</script>
```

The javascript file is as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawcolChart);

function drawcolChart(divi) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      //title: 'Company Performance',
      //hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}},
      vAxis: {title: 'Rs (Lacs)', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}},
      legend: {position: 'bottom'},
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(divi));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    document.write('wow');
  }
```

I have enqueued the javascript file successfully in the header.php. I checked that the script is enqueued by using wp_script_is function.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have already wasted 3 hours trying to debug this.

Comment: Did you actually put a script element in your javascript file ?

Comment: You can't reference a <script>-tag in a js-file. That reference will have to go on the row before you reference this js-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a script tag in the file. The script is included as script, not as HTML. Either put that script tag in the HTML page, or use Javascript to create a script tag dynamically and add to the head element.

The syntax error comes from the script tag being parsed as Javascript. The result is that nothing in the file is executed, so the function `drawcolChart` isn't created. When you later try to call it, you get the error message that it's not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a syntax error because you've put a `script` tag (html) in a javascript file.

Put 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`
 in your PHP/HTML file before you load the javascript file in order to make the javascript file run successfully.

Once you've done that you will make `drawcolChart` available in your script, for it is currently `undefined` because your javascript file failed to load.